# How to obtain a list that contains only unique values?

Tags: netlogo

I have a list as follows :

```
[[178 440] [175 440] [160 468] [160 440]]
```

The values in each sub-list correspond to coordinates x, y.

I would like to obtain a list that contains only unique values of x and y.

From the list above, the results will be:

```
[[178 440] [160 468]]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I tried with `map` but I don't know how to define the reporter with `item 0` and `item 1` Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your example, I assume that by "unique", you mean "not encountered so far".

Here is one way to do it, using the oh so flexible [`reduce`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reduce):

```
to go
  let pairs [[178 440] [175 440] [160 468] [160 440]]
  print reduce [ 
    ifelse-value (is-unique? ?2 ?1)
      [ lput ?2 ?1 ]
      [ ?1 ]
    ] fput [] pairs
end

to-report is-unique? [ pair other-pairs ]
  report
    (not member? (first pair) (map first other-pairs)) and
    (not member? (last pair) (map last other-pairs))
end
```

The `is-unique?` reporter should be fairly easy to understand: it uses [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) to extract the [`first`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#first) item (the *x*) of each of the `other-pairs`, and check that the first item of `pair` is not a [`member?`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#member) of that. It performs the same check for the [`last`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#last) item (the *y*).

The [`reduce`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reduce) part is a bit trickier, but not that hard either. We add an empty list at the front of your list of pairs (`fput [] pairs`) that we are going to use as an "accumulator" for the pairs that meet our criteria. This accumulator is going to be `?1` inside the reporter passed to `reduce`, and `?2` is going to be each of our pairs in turn. So what we do inside it is just check if `?2` is unique relative to the pairs accumulated so far. If it is, we add it to our list of accumulated pairs. If it's not, we leave the list as it was and just move on to the next `?2`.